# File not found when I use docker external network

Tags: docker

I have two local apps with `docker` container of `php`, `mariadb`, and `nginx` I'm trying to communicate both apps using curl, then I added an external network on the `docker-compose.yml`,  both apps works and the container are using the same network but the app that starts on second place gives a correct response or a `File not Found` response alternatively, and is exactly once correct once File not found , any idea about what is happening?